# SQL Query- Top 3 Sum(sal)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I want to want to get the top 3 sum(salaries) without duplicates from  the below query.
We cant use rownum as it will give duplicates. Can someone please help me here?

```
SELECT d.dname, SUM(e.sal)
FROM emp e ,dept d
WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno
GROUP BY d.dname;
```

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/top_records.php

Answer (score 1):

```
   select dname,sum(distinct sal) from 
   (SELECT d.dname dname, sal,
    dense_rank() over (partition by e.deptno order by sal desc) rn 
    FROM emp e,dept d WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno) where rn<=3 group by dname;
```

- In the inner query i queried dname,sal and also by using dense_rank() function i've given row number to the deptno wise salaries in desc order

ex:

```
dname  sal  rn
.....  ...  ...
acc    5000  1
acc    3000  2
acc    3000  2
acc    2000  3
bcc    4500  1
bcc    3000  2 .....etc
```

- in the outer i just filtered salaries by using distinct keyword

Comment: Some explanation would help future users understand your answer

Comment: @Machavity explanation added

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
Select
  Agg_Sal.Dname, 
  Agg_Sal.Total_Sal,
  Rank() Over (Partition By Dname Order By Total_Sal Desc) Rank
From 
  (Select 
    D.Dname Dname, 
    Sum(Sal) As Total_Sal 
  From 
    Emp E, Dept D
  Where
    E.Deptno = D.Deptno
  Group By
    D.Dname) Agg_Sal
Where 
  Rank <= 3
Order By 
  Rank
```

It is similar to the last example on [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions141.htm#SQLRF51667)

Answer (score 0):

If you order it by salary descending, then rownum should work:

```
select *
  from (select d.dname, sum(e.sal)
          from emp e, dept d
         where e.deptno = d.deptno
         group by d.dname
         order by 2 desc)
 where rownum <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Also use distinct function in outer query to avoid duplicate sums.

```
    select distinct(a.sumsal),a.dname
        from (select d.dname, sum(e.sal)
                   from emp e, dept d
                   where e.deptno = d.deptno
                   group by d.dname
                   order by 2 desc) a
     where rownum <= 3;
```